# jQuery .length() speed implications

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I want to find if an element exist in the DOM I use the following code.

```
if($('#target').length){
    // do stuff.
}
```

This works well and I use it quite a lot on client sites.

Question:
How fast is this method? What are the speed implications when this is used a lot in a project?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - that is wrong Michael.  `$('#target')` is never null.  It is always a valid jQuery object.  It may contain no DOM elements, but it's always a valid object.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's what I just found out in jsfiddle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be much better off using `if(document.getElementById('target'))` instead. JavaScript is always faster than jQuery (since jQuery is just a bunch of JavaScript hidden under the carpet)

EDIT: If you use it a lot, you can make a custom function:

```
function idExists(id) {return !!document.getElementById(id);}
```

Comment: thank you, I like to get my JS as fast as possible. I tend to work with intranets that run IE7 which buckles under a lot of JS.

Comment: +1 - using document.getElementById() is many times faster than constructing a jQuery object just to see if the object exists. In [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-js99/2) I short time ago, document.getElementById() was 5-10x faster (depending upon browser).

Comment: If speed is the issue, wrapping gEBI in a function will be slower than a straight call to the host method. Storing a reference is fast and less to type, e.g. `var getEl = document.getElementById;`. Be careful though, some host methods expect a certain `this` so shortening the identifier may cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

Native JS is always faster than a query through jQuery.  It just may not be as friendly.

After running a query through jsperf.com, native (`querySelectorAll`) is 57% faster than jQuery

However, if you use id, jQuery will be faster than querySelectorAll. In any case of id, use `document.getElementById` to test for an elements existence.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-obj-length

Comment: Since we're going by ID and not tag name, please do relevant tests: [`getElementById()` is significantly faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-obj-length/2)

Comment: Thank you. I will start using this method.

Comment: @etoxin - I don't understand why you chose this method.  It's many times slower than `getElementById()`.  If you're going to use plain JS, why not use the faster method?  See here for a comparison http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-js99/2

Comment: Yeah i just saw this and i'm using the `getElementById()` now.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is significantly slower.

Comment: @Kolink, I realize that the OP is using ID, but he is also obviously using a generic example. So, I used a generic example.  If you use id as the selector, jQuery will be faster in that case over querySelectorAll.  I've updated the test to use id to appease the crowds :).

Answer (score 0):

Try searching a DOM element with JQuery context say:

if an element u search say, an Input control, lies with in a table, pass table as your context:

A simple example:

```
$(function(){

var name= $('#Name','#mytab').val();

    alert(name);
});
```

the jquery engine find the element 'Name' with in 'mytab' and not the entire form

follow this fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/NzbJr/10/